# underscore "_" considered as special character in US English

Tags: special-characters

Is underscore "_" considered as special character in US English ?

Basically i am not able to figure out if I will validate my java script text with underscore as a special character.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? What difference would it make if I gave an answer "YES" or "NO"?

Comment: Actually i was validating special characters in javascript for an application . SO just wanted to know if underscore falls in the special character list

Comment: So I guess you're using JavaScript. In Haskell and Scala a plain `_` is a special identifier. As far as I know it isn't a special identifier in JavaScript. So naming a variable `_` would be fine but discouraged as the name gives no semantics. So please clarify you're question. Help us to help you.

Comment: Actually i have an application where I have to input the location and description of an emergency light . So as per my requirement special charactes cannot be used for the location and description edit box . I am using  " return !/[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/g.test(str);" to verify special character .

Comment: @ bash0  :  can i remove the underscore from my special character list ?